# Multiple tags to filter resource in AWS costexplorer using Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cost-explorer

How do you add multiple tags to filter resources using AWS golang SDK?

Hello, I have the input variable to be use for the GetCostAndUsage function from AWS SDK

```golang
input := &costexplorer.GetCostAndUsageInput{
        TimePeriod: &costexplorer.DateInterval{
            Start: aws.String(startdate.Format("2006-01-02")),
            End:   aws.String(enddate.Format("2006-01-02")),
        },
        Granularity: aws.String("MONTHLY"),
        Metrics:     []*string{aws.String("BlendedCost")},
        GroupBy: []*costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
            {
                Type: aws.String("DIMENSION"),
                Key:  aws.String("SERVICE"),
            },
        },
        Filter: &costexplorer.Expression{
            Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                Key:    aws.String("project"),
                Values: []*string{aws.String("Project1")},
                MatchOptions: []*string{
                    aws.String("EQUALS"),
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

This does works. However, I would like to filter resources using another tag which is `stage` with the values of `dev` or `prod`.

Thus I tried adding more tags in the Filter and it looked something like this

```
Filter: &costexplorer.Expression{
            Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                Key:    aws.String("project"),
                Values: []*string{aws.String("Project1")},
                MatchOptions: []*string{
                    aws.String("EQUALS"),
                },
            },
            Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                Key:    aws.String("stage"),
                Values: []*string{aws.String("dev")},
                MatchOptions: []*string{
                    aws.String("EQUALS"),
                },
            },
        },
```

Of course Go doesn't like that and gives duplicate field name tags on struct literal. Can you give me an idea on how should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `And` expression:

```golang
Filter: &costexplorer.Expression{
    And: []*costexplorer.Expression{
        {
            Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                Key:    aws.String("project"),
                Values: []*string{aws.String("Project1")},
                MatchOptions: []*string{
                    aws.String("EQUALS"),
                },
            },
        },
        {
            Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                Key:    aws.String("stage"),
                Values: []*string{aws.String("dev")},
                MatchOptions: []*string{
                    aws.String("EQUALS"),
                },
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/costexplorer#Expression

Answer (score 1):

as you can see, I added an And field to the Expression struct, which allows you to specify multiple conditions that must all be true for the filter to match. I then added two separate Expression structs to the And field, each with its own Tags field representing the project and stage tags, respectively.

Note that I also added a slice of tag values to the Values field of the stage tag, to specify both the dev and prod values.

```
input := &costexplorer.GetCostAndUsageInput{
    TimePeriod: &costexplorer.DateInterval{
        Start: aws.String(startdate.Format("2006-01-02")),
        End:   aws.String(enddate.Format("2006-01-02")),
    },
    Granularity: aws.String("MONTHLY"),
    Metrics:     []*string{aws.String("BlendedCost")},
    GroupBy: []*costexplorer.GroupDefinition{
        {
            Type: aws.String("DIMENSION"),
            Key:  aws.String("SERVICE"),
        },
    },
    Filter: &costexplorer.Expression{
        And: []*costexplorer.Expression{
            {
                Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                    Key:    aws.String("project"),
                    Values: []*string{aws.String("Project1")},
                    MatchOptions: []*string{
                        aws.String("EQUALS"),
                    },
                },
            },
            {
                Tags: &costexplorer.TagValues{
                    Key:    aws.String("stage"),
                    Values: []*string{aws.String("dev"), aws.String("prod")},
                    MatchOptions: []*string{
                        aws.String("EQUALS"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```